# C++ Compile Error - "no type named 'function' in namespace std"

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment for my C++ programming class which involves implementing a hash map. My instructor has given us a header file that we are required to use with our hash map class. The provided header file contains the line:

```
typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
```

From my (limited) understanding of C++, this would define the type HashFunction as a std::function. However, when I compile the code, I get the errors:

```
./HashMap.h:46:15: error: no type named 'function' in namespace 'std'
        typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
                ~~~~~^
./HashMap.h:46:23: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

The HashMap.h file has

```
#include <functional>
```

at the top, if it matters.

Does anyone know why I'm getting these errors?

Comment: It's C++11, so that might make a difference.

Comment: Surprised to see a school requiring C++11 in its assignments already when compiler support is still patchy at best (and at least some expertise is required to find an implementation that supports what you need it to support). Looks like it may have backfired...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a compiler with (at least partial) C++11 support. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I was using GCC 4.2, which apparently doesn't have C++11 support.  I switched to Visual Studio 2012, and it works now.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: The output looks more like Clang than that of GCC. Are you sure you were using GCC?

Comment: @NathanOsman: Recent 4.x versions of GCC now have an output similar to Clang's.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
CONFIG +=c++11
```

To the .pro file :)